# Visual C++ 2008 Redistributable Setup keeps appearing in root of E:\

Tags: visual-studio, c++, redistributable

Should I be worried? is this malware? I deleted it once but it appeared again, I have no idea what is causing this.

Comment: The VC++ Redistributable absolutely isn’t malware, as for the reason it’s being installed on your system, you probably have software installed that requires it.  Do you have software that requires it?

Comment: When does it appear? On reboot? Have you done virus scans?

Comment: Look in Programs and Features - it should be there if properly installed. Try to see what installed it. Quick Books does that and I think other programs install it as well.

Comment: Ramhound yes I have software that requires it, John it is properly installed and harrymc im gonna do a virus scan rn, I dont know when it appears, it just does

Comment: I have no viruses

Comment: Just uninstall it and reinstall it to another drive. VC++ would serve absolutely no purpose to malicious software